# Get the status for Get-SPDatabase powershell command

Tags: 2013, 2010, powershell, database

How do I get the SharePoint farm database status using below PowerShell script?

```
$baddb = Get-SPDatabase -id 25dfdfdf73-d941-4f66-9e92-18b19e7e5c79
```

It returns `Name, Typd & Id` but not `status`...

Comment: What kind of status are you expecting? Read-Only? Orphaned items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$baddb = Get-SPDatabase -id 25dfdfdf73-d941-4f66-9e92-18b19e7e5c79

$baddb | Select Name,Status
```

It should show  Name and  online or offline status based on database status

**[OutPut]**

[image]

**[Update]**

Based on your comment, in this case , you will need to show `NeedsUpgrade` that has true or false value

- False refer to no action required.
- True refer to [Database running in compatibility range and upgrade recommended](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/20/database-running-in-compatibility-range-and-upgrade-recommended/)

**EX:** get all SharePoint databases name with upgrade status

```
Get-SPDatabase  | select Name,NeedsUpgrade
```

[image]

Comment: i tried this its not showing like in central admin page _admin/DatabaseStatus.aspx status like not responding

Comment: in this case, you need to show NeedsUpgrade column, it shows false if no action required and true if require upgrade , let me update my answer based on your comment